# How to declare simple conversion operator T() in templated base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, operators

I've been working on some class hierarchy with a goal to have a collection of classes that encapsulate primitive types (`AdvancedInt`, `AdvanceDouble`, etc.) and give them some additional behavior when accessing their underlaying values, through `conversion operator` and `assignment operator`. I can't do this with getters and setter as I can't change the original code and the way it access them, so my only choice is operator overloading.

The problem I ran into is with the templated class that defines the conversion operator which gives me a compiler error.

Here is the code that illustrates the problem

```
#include <string>

class Base {
public:
    Base() = delete;
    Base(std::string s) : name(s) {
        //Some extra logic
    }
    ~Base() {
        //More custom logic
    }
    virtual std::string get_name() const final { //Final on purpose
        return name;
    }

private:
    const std::string name;
};

template <typename T, class C> class Serializable :public Base { //Poor man's interface (but not quite)
public:
    Serializable() = delete;
    Serializable(std::string name) : Base(name) {

    }
    operator T() const {
        //Some extra 'getter' logic
        return value;
    }

    C& operator=(const T& val) {
        //Some extra 'setter' logic
        value = val;
        return (C&)*this;
    }

    virtual void serialize() = 0; //This has to be pure virtual

private:
    T value;
};

class AdvancedInt final : public Serializable<int, AdvancedInt> { //This is the actual complete class
public:
    AdvancedInt(std::string name) : Serializable(name) {
        //Nothing here, but needed for the special constructor logic from AbstractBase
    }

    void serialize() override {
        //Some logic here
    }
};


int main()
{
    AdvancedInt adv{"foo"};
    
    int calc = adv;
    calc += 7;
    adv = calc; //error C2679 (msvc) | binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

    return 0;
}
```

Now aside from the (probably) questionable practice of passing `AdvancedInt` to the template of its own base class and it subsequently knowing that it's part of some derived class and implementing its logic (although any feedback on this is welcome), my main question is, what am I doing wrong here?

The `C& operator=(const T& val)` compiles fine when defined as pure virtual, but that enforces the implementation to be in the derived class, and when implemented there with `T` and `C` replaced by their corresponding types it works just fine, so the signature is logically sound, but probably not in the correct place(?). From what I've found on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment), the `simple assignment operator` is the only assignment operator that cannot be defined outside of class definition. Is this the reason why this code doesn't compile? And if so, is declaring it as pure virtual a way to go?

Comment: *"[..] practice of passing `AdvancedInt` to the template of its own base class "* It is known as [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: if you add :

using Serializable<int, AdvancedInt>::operator=;

to the class AdvancedInt, it compile with gcc 12.2

Comment: I really don't see the point of the `serialize` function being virtual. To be able to call the function, you basically need to know the type of the object to be able to call it and in that case ensuring the function is implemented could easily be done via `static_assert`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `adv = calc` we look for `operator=` from `AdvancedInt` and found (implicit):

- `AdvancedInt& operator=(const AdvancedInt&);`
- `AdvancedInt& operator=(AdvancedInt&&);`

and look-up stops there.

Adding:

```
using Serializable<int, AdvancedInt>::operator=;
```

would allow to consider also that overload.

And that fixes your issue.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GY96bEshG).

Comment: Ok, that sort of solves the problem. although if I'm going to add that `using` statement I may as well just implement the assignment operator there, which defeats the purpose of having it templated. But anyway why does the look-up stop after only two assignment operators were found? It looks like I can declare/template that operator and that it is there, but I have to explicitly bring it into derived class? Why is that templated one not visible by default? Is this the language limitation (or a missing feature/bug)? Or is there a good reason for it to work this way, that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @NRUB: Once the name has been found in some scope, it proceeds to carry out overload resolution on whatever implementations of that name are in that scope. If that fails, compilation fails--it does not look for more overloads at other scopes. As for what it does that: it's a long story, but it ultimately comes down to interacting badly with implicit conversions.

Comment: @NRUB: Look up stops at first scope where it founds the expected name. As pro, it allows to avoid to break derived classes by adding new functions in base class (with same name as derived's ones). More details about overload resolution [there](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Call_to_an_overloaded_operator).